# C# Best way to iterate a tree structure of links

Tags: c#

I'm trying to gather a list of website links which starting from the root directory can branch down to many sub-directory links, below is a link to a simplified graphic which illustrates the structure, I'm only concerned with getting links in Green, Yellow links always lead to other links, so my output array would contain A,B,D,F,G,H,I. I'm trying to code this in C#.

[image]

Comment: That isn't really all that helpful on its own.  What is the *code* structure of that tree.  That's what's relevant.

Comment: Where are you taking that structure from? No code is possible if we don't know what are you trying, where that data comes from, the type of the data and others.

Comment: I've tried to make it simple, A,B,C,D represent the links in the root folder

Comment: [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) would be what I'd use. The reading of the nodes/links is irrelevant to the question asked (because it was not asked about!); or the fundamental 'way' used.

Comment: Are you scraping this from some site you do not control? If you do control this site, are you trying to generate the tree from an MVC routing table or something, or do you have the tree stored somewhere?

Comment: have you tried looking around, what is out there already...https://github.com/sjdirect/abot

Comment: Yes, I'm scraping from a site that I don't control

Comment: The problem here unless you know the entire structure of the site beforehand is that you have to build the tree *first*, then you can evaluate whether or not the node is a leaf node or a branch. There isn't an easy way to determine if a link has sub-links unless you visit the link first.

Comment: Well...you probably want to use a binary search tree-like algorithm. This link might help you get an idea: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379572(v=vs.80).aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In generic terms, you can do something like

```
    private static IEnumerable<T> Leaves<T>(T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSource)
    {
        var children = childSource(root).ToList();
        if (!children.Any()) {
            yield return root;
            yield break;
        }
        foreach (var descendant in children.SelectMany(child => Leaves(child, childSource)))
        {
            yield return descendant;
        }
    }
```

Here, childSource is assumed to be a function that can take an element and return that element's children.  In your case, you'll want to make a function that uses something like HtmlAgilityPack to take a given url, download it, and return links from that.

```
    private static string Get(int msBetweenRequests, string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
            using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            using (var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var result = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null; // really nothing sensible to do here
        }
        finally
        {
            // let's be nice to the server we're crawling
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(msBetweenRequests);
        }
    }


    private static IEnumerable<string> ScrapeForLinks(string url)
    {
        var noResults = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

        var html = Get(1000, url);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(html)) return noResults;

        var d = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        d.LoadHtml(html);
        var links = d.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
        return links == null ? noResults :
            links.Select(
                link => 
                    link
                    .Attributes
                    .Where(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "href")
                    .Select(a => a.Value)
                    .First()
             )
             .Select(linkUrl => FixRelativePaths(url, linkUrl))
                    ;

    }

    private static string FixRelativePaths(string baseUrl, string relativeUrl)
    {
        var combined = new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl), relativeUrl);
        return combined.ToString();
    }
```

Note that, in a naive approach, you'll run into an infinite loop if there are any cycles in the links between these pages.  To alleviate this, you'll want to avoid expanding the children of a url you've visited before.

```
    private static Func<string, IEnumerable<string>> DontVisitMoreThanOnce(Func<string, IEnumerable<string>> naiveChildSource)
    {
        var alreadyVisited = new HashSet<string>();
        return s =>
        {
            var children = naiveChildSource(s).Select(RemoveTrailingSlash).ToList();
            var filteredChildren = children.Where(c => !alreadyVisited.Contains(c)).ToList();
            alreadyVisited.UnionWith(children);
            return filteredChildren;
        };
    }

    private static string RemoveTrailingSlash(string url)
    {
        return url.TrimEnd(new[] {'/'});
    }
```

In case you'd like to prevent your crawler from escaping onto the internet and spending time on Youtube, you'll want

```
    private static Func<string, IEnumerable<string>> DontLeaveTheDomain(
        string domain,
        Func<string, IEnumerable<string>> wanderer)
    {
        return u => wanderer(u).Where(l => l.StartsWith(domain));
    }
```

Once you've defined these things, what you want is just

```
    var results = Leaves(
        myUrl,
        DontLeaveTheDomain(
            myDomain, 
            DontVisitMoreThanOnce(ScrapeForLinks)))
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, will try this out later and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I'm trying to use your code but my VS does not recognize the method "Flatten", what namespace/class does it belong to?

Comment: Sorry, renamed Flatten to Leaves and screwed that up.  Edited.

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code but it doesn't seem to work for me, the "DontVisitMoreThanOnce" method only gets called once, I've setup a test directory which has the same structure as the graphic above at this url http://www.kitchenireland.com/Test/

Comment: There are a couple corner cases I didn't take into account, so I'll be posting an edit soon.  Amusingly, I didn't take into account the implied restriction that we should only visit pages on the same domain as the initial request, which led my crawler on an odyssey through various statcounter domains, to some random blog, to google, and finally to youtube.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks for your response, yes this would only follow links contained within a single domain, like those in the link above, I look forward to your update

Comment: Edited.  In the usage given at the end, myDomain can be any url prefix.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, just one thing though when I run the code for this url http://www.kitchenireland.com/Test/ , it captures all links across the entire domain, my preferred output would just the links from the "Test" directory downwards, so A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear: when I say myDomain can be any url prefix, I mean you can set 

    var myDomain = "http://" + "kitchenireland.com/Test"

and it won't visit the rest of the site. (The string concatenation there is just to stop StackOverflow from eating the "http://")

Comment: Brilliant, that did the trick now, I'll package your code into a Utility class for future use, thanks once again for your help as this coding problem was way over my head :)